# efficient per column matrix indexing in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two matrices of the same size, A, B. I want to use the columns of B to acsses the columns of A, on a per column basis. For example,

```
A = np.array([[1, 4, 7],
              [2, 5, 8],
              [3, 6, 9]])
```

and

```
B = np.array([[0, 0, 2],
              [1, 2, 1],
              [2, 1, 0]])
```

I want something like:

```
A[B] = [[1, 4, 9],  
        [2, 6, 8], 
        [3, 5, 7]]
```

I.e., I've used the j'th column of B as indices to the j'th column of A.
Is there any effiecnt way of doing so?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
A[B, np.arange(A.shape[0])]

array([[1, 4, 9],
       [2, 6, 8],
       [3, 5, 7]])
```

Or with [`np.take_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html):

```
np.take_along_axis(A, B, axis=0)

array([[1, 4, 9],
       [2, 6, 8],
       [3, 5, 7]])
```

Comment: Amazing works great. Just to make sure I understand what is happening in the first suggestion: you index A at axis 0 with the index Bij, while at axis 1 the vector np.arange(A.shape[0]) is broadcasted to the same shape as B?

Comment: Exactly @MRm Internally both indexing arrays are broadcast together to the resulting shape. The arange is just specifying which columns each value in the rows of `B` correspond to. Find a detailed explanation along with examples [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-indexing-explained-c376abb2440d)