# Numpy matrix: select column based on list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array and a list that list that defines the rows I want to select.
What is the best way to do this operation?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])

b = np.array([[1],
              [0],
              [2]])
```

Desired result

```
np.array([[2],
         [4],
         [9]])
```

I have tried np.take() but this does not work.

Kind regards

EDIT: as this needs to be done repeatedly on a large array, I'm looking for a vectorized approach (without loops)

Comment: What is the mathematical logic to achieve this?

Comment: For each row in `a` you select the element at the column defined by `b`

Comment: You thus want the 1st element of the first row of `a`, the 0th element of the second row and the 2nd element of the last row (as defined in `b`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy selecting specific column index per row by using a list of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435782/numpy-selecting-specific-column-index-per-row-by-using-a-list-of-indexes)

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the extraneous dimensions from `b`

```
b = np.sqeeze(b)
```

You can use the following:

```
a[np.arange(len(b)), b]
```

Comment: Take a look at the newish `np.take_along_axis`

Answer (score 1):

It's not very pythonic but this should do the trick for your problem:

```
res = np.zeros(len(b))
for i, row in enumerate(a):
    res[i] = row[b[i]]

print(res)
```

same in one line:

```
a[[i[0] for i in b],[i for i in range(len(b))]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the desired action! Is there a way to do it without loops?

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions have added a `take_along_axis` which does what you want:

```
In [96]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], 
    ...:               [4,5,6], 
    ...:               [7,8,9]]) 
    ...:  
    ...: b = np.array([[1], 
    ...:               [0], 
    ...:               [2]])                                                                           
In [97]: np.take_along_axis(a,b,axis=1)                                                                
Out[97]: 
array([[2],
       [4],
       [9]])
```

It works much like [@Nils answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61229950/901925), `a[np.arange(3), np.squeeze(b)]`, but handles the dimensions better.

Similar recent questions:

[efficient per column matrix indexing in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61172273/efficient-per-column-matrix-indexing-in-numpy)

[keep elements of an np.ndarray by values of another np.array (vectorized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61225957/keep-elements-of-an-np-ndarray-by-values-of-another-np-array-vectorized)

Comment: This is indeed what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
np.array([a[i,b[i]] for i in range(len(b))]
```